# Change size of depth Axis in rotated view

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, teechart

Using Delphi XE with TeeChart Pro 2011 on Windows 7.

I have a chart which shows the height differences of a disc (in nano-meters). 
In total there are 100 rectangular fields each with about 1000 data points, almost evenly distributed on the disc. The field at the edges are only partially filled as there is no data outside the disc. `IrregularGrid := True;` is required to see the data properly.
Ideally, I'd use a `TColorGridseries`, as that would provide exactly the (2d)view I want to achieve. Unfortunately the distribution of the data is such that the `TColorGridseries` simply does not function properly (Known TChart bug).

I turned to the `TSurfaceSeries`, which can handle the data properly. The main disadvantage is that the 3d aspect puts the Z values on the left axis and the Y values on the depth axis. This results in a side view of the disc. To compensate I can rotate the 3d chart so I get a top view again, however the depth axis is drawn such that I get a chart rectangle with a 1:10 ratio.

My question in the end is simple:
Is there a way to set the (pixel)length of the depth axis to the same (pixel)length as the horizontal axis, so that I get a 1:1 ratio for the top view of a 3d chart?

Regards,
deColaman

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an option is doing something similar to the *All features\Welcome !\Axes\Isometric Axis*" example in the features demo but extending it to a 3D chart, similar to what was discussed [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7885&hilit=isometric%20depth). This is a TeeChart ActiveX and VB6 example but same principles apply to the VCL version. You can also download a more complete Delphi example [here](http://teechart.net/files/public/IsoAxis3D.zip). It will probably be pretty close to what you are looking for.

Comment: The IsoAxis example actually changes the range of the depth axis, not the size of the axis. Although this gets the aspect ratio right it is not what I need. Another issue with TChart is that the Depth axis on its side(i.e. 3d% = 100) ignores common constraints like the margins around the chart resulting in my circle falling off the top of the chart component. Zooming, Panning and TShapes also appear to be done for the XY plane only, not for the Z plane, which causes strange behaviour.